# Undefined data when using vuex and vue-router

Tags: vue.js, promise, undefined, vuex, vue-router

I'm having an issue with the initial state of data in my application. I'm using vuex and vue-router, and I think the async stuff is tripping me up, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

In my view.vue component:

```js
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
  store.dispatch('assignments/getAssignment', {
    id: to.params.id
  }).then(res => next());
},
```

In my module:

```js
getAssignment({commit, state}, {id}) {
    return axios.get('/assignments/' + id)
            .then(response => {
                if(response.data.data.type == 'goal_plan') {
                    const normalizedEntity = normalize(response.data.data, assignment_schema);
                    commit('goals/setGoals', {goals: normalizedEntity.entities.goals}, {root: true});
                    commit('goals/setGoalStrategicPriorities', {goal_priorities: normalizedEntity.entities.strategicPriorities}, {root: true});
                    commit('goals/setObjectives', {objectives: normalizedEntity.entities.objectives}, {root: true});
                    commit('goals/setStrategies', {strategies: normalizedEntity.entities.strategies}, {root: true});
                }
                commit('setAssignment', {assignment: response.data.data});
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
                EventBus.$emit('error-thrown', error);
            });
},
```

A couple of subcomponents down, I want to access state.goals.goals, but it is initially undefined. I can handle some of the issues from that, but not all.

For example, I have a child component of view.vue that includes

```js
computed: {
    originalGoal() {
      return this.$store.getters['goals/goalById'](this.goalId);
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      form: {
        id: this.originalGoal.id,
        description: this.originalGoal.description,
        progress_type: this.originalGoal.progress_type,
        progress_values: {
          to_reach: this.originalGoal.progress_values.to_reach,
          achieved: this.originalGoal.progress_values.achieved,
        },
        due_at: moment(this.originalGoal.due_at).toDate(),
        status: this.originalGoal.status,
      },
```

In the heady days before I started using vuex, I was passing in the original goal as a prop, so it wasn't an issue. Since it's now pulled from the state, I get a bunch of errors that it can't find the various properties of undefined. Eventually originalGoal resolves in the display, but it's never going to show up in the form this way.

I tried "watch"ing the computed prop, but I never saw when it changed, and I'm pretty sure that's not the right way to do it anyway.

So, is there a way to get the data set initially? If not, how should I go about setting the form values once the data IS set? (Any other suggestions welcome, as I'm pretty new to vuex and vue-router.)

Comment: I think it is because you are trying to get the originalGoal in data(). Why don't you directly access the computed in the form. For example, <input type="text" v-model="originalGoal.description">

Comment: You appear to be implementing the [explicit promise construction anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Don't do that

Comment: To expand on Phils comment, `axios.get` returns a Promise, so you don't need to wrap it in another Promise. You can do `return axios.get()...` directly.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated to remove the explicit promise construction and just return axios.get(). Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

So if I set the form values in "mounted," I'm able to get this to work. Still learning about the vue life-cycle I guess. :)